Chart.Js Chart's layout is not updated in storybook
my goal
I'm trying to make Chart preview with using StroyBook and Chart.Js.
what I Did

make Chart Component with using Chart.Js
make Story Component with using Chart Component

versions
"chart.js": "^4.4.4",
"chartjs-chart-funnel": "^4.2.2",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
"storybook": "^8.3.3",

what I expect
if i change type arg, preview Chart is gonna change properly
what happened
chart is updated but, the previous chart's layout still leave in canvas.
In particular, if I select a radar, bubble, or scatter type and then select another type, the layout of that type chart will remain.
so This is Chart Component it self looks like

seems normal but when i make Storybook Component With using this component, This happens

As you can see, the type of chart has changed, but the external layout of the chart has remained, which makes for a messy mess later on.
Chart Component Code
    const Chart = (props: {
      type:
        | "line"
        | "bar"
        | "bubble"
        | "doughnut"
        | "pie"
        | "polarArea"
        | "radar"
        | "scatter"
        | "funnel";
      data: {
        labels?: string[];
        datasets: {
          label: string;
          type?:
            | "line"
            | "bar"
            | "bubble"
            | "doughnut"
            | "pie"
            | "polarArea"
            | "radar"
            | "scatter"
            | "funnel";
          data:
            | number[]
            | {
                x: number;
                y: number;
                r: number;
              }[]
            | {
                x: number;
                y: number;
              }[]
            | [number, number][];
          backgroundColor?: string[] | string;
          borderColor?: string[] | string;
          borderWidth?: number;
          fill?: boolean;
          pointBackgroundColor?: string;
          pointBorderColor?: string;
          pointHoverBackgroundColor?: string;
          pointHoverBorderColor?: string;
        }[];
      };
      options?: object;
      width?: number;
      height?: number;
    }) => {
      const { type, data, options, width, height } = props;
      const canvasEl = React.useRef(null);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasEl.current;
        const ctx = (canvas as unknown as HTMLCanvasElement).getContext("2d");
        if (ctx) {
          const chart = ChartJs.getChart(ctx);
          const drawChart = async () => {
            new ChartJs(ctx, {
              type,
              data,
              options,
              plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            });
          };
          chart?.destroy();
          drawChart();
        }
      }, [type, data, options]);
    
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            height: "40vh",
            width: "80vw",
          }}
        >
          <canvas id="Chart" ref={canvasEl} width={width} height={height}></canvas>
        </div>
      );
    };
export default Chart;

StoryBook Component Code


const meta = {
  title: "Component/Chart",
  component: Chart,
  decorators: (Story) => {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexDirection: "column",
          gap: 16,
        }}
      >
        <Story />
      </div>
    );
  },
  tags: ["autodocs"],
  argTypes: {
    width: {
      control: "number",
    },
    height: {
      control: "number",
    },
    type: {
      control: "radio",
      options: [
        "line",
        "bar",
        "pie",
        "doughnut",
        "radar",
        "polarArea",
        "bubble",
        "scatter",
      ],
    },
    data: {
      control: "object",
    },
    options: {
      control: "object",
    },
  },
  args: {
    type: "bar",
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,

    data: {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],

      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First Dataset",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
            "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)",
          ],
          borderColor: [
            "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
            "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
            "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
            "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
            "rgb(201, 203, 207)",
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
   
  },
} satisfies Meta<typeof Chart>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;



export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    type: "bar",
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,

    data: {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First Dataset",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
          backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
            "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
            "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
            "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)",
          ],
          borderColor: [
            "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
            "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
            "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
            "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
            "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
            "rgb(201, 203, 207)",
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "top" as const,
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Chart.js Chart",
        },
      },
    },
  },

  render: function Render(args) {
    const [{ type }, updateArgs] = useArgs();
    console.log(type);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (type === "bubble") {
        updateArgs({
          type: "bubble",
          data: {
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "First Dataset",
                data: [
                  {
                    x: 20,
                    y: 30,
                    r: 15,
                  },
                  {
                    x: 40,
                    y: 10,
                    r: 10,
                  },
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                ],
                borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      } else if (type === "scatter") {
        updateArgs({
          type: "scatter",
          data: {
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "First Dataset",
                data: [
                  {
                    x: 20,
                    y: 30,
                  },
                  {
                    x: 40,
                    y: 10,
                  },
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                ],
                borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      } else {
        updateArgs({
          type,
          data: {
            labels: [
              "January",
              "February",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "June",
              "July",
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "My First Dataset",
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                  "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)",
                ],
                borderColor: [
                  "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                  "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
                  "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
                  "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                  "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                  "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
                  "rgb(201, 203, 207)",
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      }
    }, [type, updateArgs]);

    const { ...rest } = args;
    return <Chart {...rest} />;
  },
};


